# Cannot Position Figures Correctly

Tags: floats

I am writing my senior thesis on latex. I've been using latex for a few years but I always have issues positioning the figures. Sometimes, I can place them whereever I want with use of !h, p, t parameters etc. But at this time, I stuck.

What I want to do is simply as it follows:

- A paragraph
- A figure
- Second Paragraph
- Second figure

What I get is

- First and second paragraph
- The figures

When I scale the figures to a smaller size, I get the correct order of placing. But I want to use the figures bigger.

[image]

As you can see the problem is caused because there is not enough space to put the figure down below the first paragraph because it is at the end of the page. So why not put the figure on top of a new page and then place the second paragraph below the first figure? I think you understand my problem here. How can I solve this? Please I'm outta my mind. Thanks

Comment: you could simply use `\includegraphics` the only function of the `figure` environment is to allow the figure to be moved to help with page breaking. If you use `[h]` then you are preventing `t` so the figure cant be placed at the top of the next page. latex warns about this and changes it to `[ht]`  but including  `p` as well is better. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text  but it is better not to force the position and dont assume the figure is at a fixed place but refer to it indirectly via its number, that is why figures have numbered captions.

Comment: I looked for it, it didn't work out. I still can't fix the problem.

Comment: the figures moving is a feature not a problem to be solved, but if you really do not want that, do as it says at the link, use `\usepackage{float}`  and `\begin{figure}[H]` and the figures will go exactly where you place them.

Comment: As I told you, it did not work... I already told that I did what the link says but it still is acting weird. Here is my code and output; 

https://imgur.com/a/Mz8dAMR

PS: I included \usepackage{float} at the beginning of latex.

Comment: if you use `[H]` thenn the figure will not move from where you place it in the source. The figre will appear between the paragraphs where you place it.  If  you believe you have found a bug in that code (which has been used by millions of people for decades)  that is fine but you need to provide an example that shows the problem, edit your question a complete small document  with a figure using `[H]` that does not appear where you expect. You can use `example-image` as the image as it is availabe for such tests.

Comment: The output that you describe can not happen if `[H]` is working. It is of course possible that code you are loading in the preamble has redefined `figure` to undo the float package defining `[H]` but as you have not shown any code no one can help with that,

Comment: Note that if you do not load float package then `[H]` forces the figures to the end of the document as it means not h not t not b not p so the float is not allowed anywhere.